# how do I see stack trace of warnings/errors which appear in the console as "(node: SOME_NUMBER)"

Tags: node.js, debugging

My console is showing things like

```
(node:27266) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27266) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It would be so helpfull if I could see the stack trace at these points

Comment: As the warning says, you are missing a `.catch` somewhere in your code. One of the promises is rejected somewhere in the code which is not handled. Try adding `.catch(console.log)` at appropriate places. BTW, that is `(node:<pid>) `

Comment: Thanks, now I have to find what a pid is. I have too much unorganised code to single out appropriate places, the original js file calls many others so that gets even harder.

Comment: `pid` is `process id` a unique identifier your OS uses to point to a running process. For the most cases. `pid` will not help you solve the issue you've mentioned.

Comment: beyond the specific error, it would be great to setup node to just declare the running code LINE ... instead of just the running code PID

Comment: I did not know we could do that, pretty please point me towards something that shows me how to do this ...